# Get Gridview Textbox value as Date Format

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am using asp.net Textbox inside Gridview and accessing Textbox using below code;

**ASP.NET**

```
<ItemTemplate>                       
     <asp:TextBox runat="server" TextMode="Date"  Title="Select Received Date." AutoCompleteType="Disabled" placeholder="Receive On (Date)" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" ID="txtRcvOn" Visible="false" ></asp:TextBox>
</ItemTemplate>
```

**C#**

`TextBox txtRcvOn0 = (row.Cells[7].FindControl("txtRcvOn") as TextBox);`
and have tried to below code to get date format;

```
               1- string RcvOn = DateTime.Parse((row.Cells[7].FindControl("txtRcvOn") as TextBox).Text).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
               2- DateTime dt = new DateTime();
               3- dt = DateTime.ParseExact(txtRcvOnn.Text, "yyyy/MM/dd", null);
               4- string txtRcvOn = Convert.ToDateTime(txtRcvOnn).ToString();
               5- string txtRcvOn = Convert.ToDateTime(txtRcvOn0.Text).ToString();
               6- DateTime txtdate = DateTime.ParseExact(txtRcvOnn.Text, "MM/dd/yy", null);
               7- string txtRcvOn = Convert.ToDateTime(txtRcvOn0.Text).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy", DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo);
               8- int txtRcvOn = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[7].Text);
               9- string txtRcvOn = GridView1.Rows[0].Cells[7].Text.ToString();
```

But all code are given ERRORS i.e.
`String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.` and in some codes the date save as 01/01/1900.
How can I fix this???

Comment: this `Visible="false"` make this textbox not even render - so you get an empty string  - beside that - can you debug step by step to see what you get there

Comment: Using a Link Button I set it as ```Visible="true"``` before using its value.

Answer (score 0):

If you make your control invisible (`Visible="false"`) the control won't be rendered.
Use `<asp:HiddenField>`:

```
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="txtRcvOn" />
```

If you cannot use `<asp:HiddenField>`, use the following:

```
<input type=“hidden” runat=“server” id=“hdnControl” Value=“2” />
```

If you confirm you get data from your field then try this to convert string to datetime: you will get exception if there is no valid DateTime in Textbox.

```
DateTime myDate= Convert.ToDateTime(txtRcvOnn.Text);
```

or you  can use this:

```
DateTime myDate;
if (!DateTime.TryParse(txtRcvOnn.Text, out myDate))
{
    myDate = DateTime.Now; //If failed date time will be current date
}
```

Comment: Got same error ```String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.```

Comment: answer updated, try now

Comment: Before using this textbox I set it as ```Visible="true"``` and where have to put this code ```<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="txtRcvOn" />``` ?

Comment: ```<asp:TextBox runat="server" TextMode="Date"  Title="Select Received Date." AutoCompleteType="Disabled" placeholder="Receive On (Date)" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" ID="txtRcvOn" Visible="false" ></asp:TextBox> ``` replace this with ```<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="txtRcvOn" /> ```